# htaccess: remove portion of url gives Internal Server Access

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to flatten my website structure. I have paths which were like mydomain.com/clearos/ClearOS_7.x/7.4/README that I'd like to change to /clearos/ClearOS_7.x/README. A while ago I did this by making the folder 7.4 a symlink back to /ClearOS_7.x and this works (except for some web crawlers or someone, I think, who goes for /7.4/7.4/ etc.

I've tried to add different .htaccess rules, but each one I try gives an http 500 internal server error. The .htaccess is in the document root and these are what I've tried (separately):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)/7.4/(.*) $1/$2 [R=301]
RewriteRule (.*)/7\.4/(.*) $1/$2 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^clearos/ClearOS_7\.x/7\.4/(.*)$ clearos/ClearOS_7.x/$1 [R=301,L]
```

All three forms seem to do what I want in the .htaccess checker at https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

If it is relevant I am using Apache 2.4

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, Nick.

[edit]

Hmm. I'm seeing

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

And yet if I have an http -> https rewrite rule afterwards, it works fine. Not sure what is going on. More investigation needed.

Playing around some more and changing the 301 to a 302, with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/7.4/(.*) $1/$2 [NC,R=302]
```

It keeps rewriting mydomain.com/clearos/ClearOS_7.x/7.4/README to mydomain.com/var/www/html/clearos/ClearOS_7.x/README. I've tried telling Firefox to forget the site, but now, whatever I do I get the same.

[/edit]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer seems to be to add:

```
RewriteBase "/"
```